# Numpy not working with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, aws-lambda

I am trying to create bar charts (using Matplotlib) to be saved in an AWS S3 bucket. It works perfectly from my laptop but when I upload the code to AWS Lambda (with the right packages installed) I get an error. Here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from boto3 import Session
import io

from datetime import date

months = [date(2018, month, 1).strftime('%b') for month in range(1, 13)]
filename = 'barplot.png'
BUCKET = 'my_bucket_name'

img_data = io.BytesIO()

counts = [
    [606, 124, 759, 998, 234],
    [762, 912, 639, 591, 135],
    [492, 92, 119, 1131, 999],
]

plt.figure()
plt.title('Fantastic Title Goes Here')
plt.xlabel('Timeline')
plt.ylabel('base count')

x1 = [2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0]
x2 = [x - 0.5 for x in x1]
x3 = [x + 0.5 for x in x1]

plt.xticks(x1, months)

plt.bar(x3, counts[2], width=0.4, color="#ff0000", label="Bar 3 Label")
plt.bar(x2, counts[1], width=0.4, color="#87CEEB", label="Bar 2 Label")
plt.bar(x1, counts[0], width=0.4, color="#F4A460", label="Bar 1 Label")

plt.legend()

plt.axis([0.5, 25, 0, 1500])
# NOTE saving to a file: plt.savefig(filename)

plt.savefig(img_data, format='png')
img_data.seek(0)


s3 = Session().client('s3')

response = s3.put_object(Body=img_data, Bucket=BUCKET, ContentType='image/png',
                         Key=filename, ACL='public-read')
```

I am getting the following error:
**ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'**

Here's the error Traceback:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "/var/task/support_functions/catch_exceptions.py", line 19, in wrapper
return function(*args, **kwargs)
File "/var/task/jokes/flow_jokes.py", line 13, in get_joke
import support_functions.charts
File "/var/task/support_functions/charts.py", line 1, in < module >
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/var/task/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 127, in < module >
from . import cbook
File "/var/task/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 35, in < module >
import numpy as np
File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in < module >
from . import add_newdocs
File "/var/task/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in < module >
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "/var/task/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in < module >
from .type_check import *
File "/var/task/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in < module >
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "/var/task/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 26, in < module >
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed. Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean - xdf` (removes all
                                                                files not under version control). Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

Obviously I tried to uninstall and reinstall numpy and matplotlib jointly and seperately several times with no success.

Tks.

Comment: On the AWS Lambda console, go to Actions > Export function > Download deployment package. Check if the multiarray module is part of the downloaded package. If not, make sure you have your deployment package when you upload look the same as your local environment.

Comment: @DeividiSilva, thanks.... I did what you said and, indeed, it does look exactly the same (especially the numpy package which seems to be causing the problem). Is there anything I can do about it? Tks.

Comment: Did you locally install numpy and then zip it into your package for deployment? Check out this document on creating the deployment package: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: yes off course we did..... we've deployed much more complicated stuff on AWS Lambda (with lots of packages) using either cloudformation or SAM, so the issue is not there. Plus as mentioned earlier, the downloaded package looks EXACTLY like the one running locally .....

Comment: Check out this thread: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9272 . Maybe the problem is with the python version being different in aws lambda.

Comment: could very well be......I guess my only choice is to ask AWS team to solve it in this case.